# XPath not returning everything after element

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm retrieving a `ul > li` of ingredients from my site, then I'm using foreach to loop through each `li`.

Inside the `<li></li>` it contains information in the following format: `<strong>1-2 tablespoons</strong> <a href="link">coconut oil</a> (to taste)`, not all contains hyperlinks, it's random.

All I'm trying to do is break up the data so I can put them into an array like so:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'amount' => 2 ounces,
        'ingredients' => pre-cooked chicken
    ),
    1 => array(
        'amount' => 1-2 tablespoons,
        'ingredients' => coconut oil (to taste)
    )
);
```

While maintaining the html a link in the coconut oil part.

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
$string is an array with the li content
foreach($string as $data){
    $try = new \DOMdocument;
    $try->loadHTML($data);
    $find = new \DOMXPath($try);

    // from this point it's where I'm having problems
    $x = $find->query('//li');
    foreach($x as $data){
        echo '<pre>', print_r($data), '</pre>';
    }
}
```

The print_r($data) returns the following DOMElement Objects (with other empty keys like parentNode, childNode, firstChild, previousSibling):

```
DOMElement Object (
    [tagName] => li
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => li
    [nodeValue] => 2 ounces pre-cooked chicken
    [nodeType] => 1
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [localName] => li
    [textContent] => 2 ounces pre-cooked chicken
)
DOMElement Object (
    [tagName] => li
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => li
    [nodeValue] => 1-2 tablespoons coconut oil (to taste)
    [nodeType] => 1
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [localName] => li
    [textContent] => 1-2 tablespoons coconut oil (to taste)
)
```

I thought it would be best to break up the information, in 1 query I just get all of the data inside the strong tag, but the issue that I'm having is actually just getting all of the content after the strong tag.

Here I try to get all of the content after the strong tag:

```
$list = $find->query('//strong/following-sibling::text()');
foreach($list as $data){
    $i[] = $try->saveHTML($data);
}
```

If I `print_r($i)` I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  pre-cooked chicken
    [1] =>  
    [2] =>  (to taste)
)
```

but if I change the query to `$list = $find->query('//strong/following-sibling::*')` all I get is the following which is a hyperlink.

```
Array
(
    [0] => coconut oil
)
```

**Update:**

**Input array:**

```
Array (
    [0] => <strong>2 ounces</strong> pre-cooked chicken
    [1] => <strong>1-2 tablespoons</strong> <a href="/link">coconut oil</a> (to taste)
)
```

And

**Expected output:**

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'amount' => 2 ounces,
        'ingredients' => pre-cooked chicken
    ),
    1 => array(
        'amount' => 1-2 tablespoons,
        'ingredients' => <a href="/link">coconut oil</a> (to taste)
    )
);
```

Comment: @Can you share HTML Source string and expected output?

Comment: @SahilGulati I've updated the question, any ideas?

Comment: Are you expecting something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting something like this? Hope this seems to be helpful. Here we are using `preg_match`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/858266)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$result=array();
$array=Array (
    0 => "<strong>2 ounces</strong> pre-cooked chicken",
    1 => '<strong>1-2 tablespoons</strong> <a href="/link">coconut oil</a> (to taste)'
);
foreach($array as $data) 
{
    preg_match("/<strong>(.*?)(?:<\/strong>)(.*)/",$data,$matches);
    $result[]=array(
        "amount"=>$matches[1],
        "ingredients"=>$matches[2]
    );
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Yes Sahil, that works without any hitches. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Sahil, I've got another quick question related towards preg_match. What if I have two strong tags randomly in the tags like so https://eval.in/858332

Comment: @Johnson Can you share the expected output than? When we have more than one strong tags.

Comment: Exact same output as the last question, but I just remembered that there are random arrays with more than 1 strong tag. I put the expected result in here: https://eval.in/858348

Comment: What would you recommend then? I appreciate your answer by the way, this is the second time you've helped me in a tight spot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153975/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-johnson).

Comment: @Johnson usually i dont recommend parsing of HTML tags without `DOMDocument` but for your updated used case you can try this one eval.in/858367